# DBNull replaces with DateTime.MinValue

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datetime

I want to check if BirthDate comes as a NULL in DB then i need to pass the DateTime.MinValue

```
 var da = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(d => new StaffModel
                {
                    empbirthday= d.Field<DateTime>("BIRTH_DATE"),

                });
```

Now BIRTH_DATE comes as a DBNull.. I want to pass if this comes as a DBNull then need to pass DateTime.MinValue(embbirthday is a non nullable type)

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: Create function and use it in linq, and check everything what you want in function

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're looking for, try to elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Try using combination of nullable DateTime and null coalescing operator

```
empbirthday= d.Field<DateTime?>("BIRTH_DATE") ?? DateTime.MinValue,
```